# Trying to change variable using a checkbox in AHK, but it doesn't seem to be changing the variable at all?

Tags: autohotkey

I've been trying to make a pretty basic toggle button to turn hotkeys on and off, but it doesn't seem to be updating the "MyHotkeyCheckboxState" variable at all?

I tried changing it to this script to troubleshoot, but the box is just empty. Any ideas or anything big I'm missing?

```
; Create a GUI window with a checkbox control
Gui, Add, Checkbox, vMyHotkeyCheckboxState, Enable Hotkey
Gui, Show

; Create a hotkey using PgUp as the keybind
Hotkey, PgUp, MyHotkey, On
return


; Toggle the hotkey based on the state of the checkbox
MyHotkey:
     MsgBox, %MyHotkeyCheckboxState%
return
```

Answer (score 1):

The checkbox status wasn't saved to the variable yet when you checked for it in the MsgBox command.

You just need to add `Gui, Submit, NoHide` every time you want to check for the checkbox state. `NoHide` is there so that the target GUI doesn't get hidden.

```
; Create a GUI window with a checkbox control
Gui, Add, Checkbox, vMyHotkeyCheckboxState, Enable Hotkey
Gui, Show

; Create a hotkey using PgUp as the keybind
Hotkey, PgUp, MyHotkey, On
return


; Toggle the hotkey based on the state of the checkbox
MyHotkey:
    Gui, Submit, NoHide
    MsgBox, %MyHotkeyCheckboxState%
return
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using [GuiControlGet](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/GuiControlGet.htm)

```
; Create a GUI window with a checkbox control
Gui, Add, Checkbox, vMyHotkeyCheckboxState, Enable Hotkey
Gui, Show

; Create a hotkey using PgUp as the keybind
Hotkey, PgUp, MyHotkey
Return

; Toggle the hotkey based on the state of the checkbox
MyHotkey:
    GuiControlGet, MyHotkeyCheckboxState
    MsgBox, %MyHotkeyCheckboxState%
Return
```